# How do I complete these fragments?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-fragments, is-it-a-sentence

Simply Put, I have the following(similar) sentences:

> Transducer Introduction.
>
> An introduction to Transducer/Sensor.
>
> A methodology to meet the deadlines.
>
> Introduction to XYZ.

**All** of these are marked **GREEN** by *Microsoft's grammar check*. Those Green lines are really ***Annoying*** . Whats the proper way to write these Fragments so that the *Grammar Check* spares me.

**Update:**

I learned from some answers that *Microsoft's Grammar Check* is way too sensitive. And it has a habit of annoyance. Still, is there some way I can solve the problem?

Comment: Is there some way you can solve the problem? Sure: Turn off grammar check.  For years, this was my first action when starting to use Word on a new computer.  Nowadays, though, grammar check seems to be off by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one of your fragments is an acceptable title already and doesn't need revision.  To keep a particular title or section from being grammar checked,

> Select the text you want skipped, then, double-click the language indicator in the status bar (or choose Tools - Language - Set Language), and enable “Do not check spelling or grammar”. [Herb Tyson, in article [Disable spell check section](http://help.lockergnome.com/office/Disable-spell-check-section--ftopict988864.html)]

Regarding the titles shown:  Use plural forms of *transducer* and *sensor*; remove the article before *deadlines*; replace */* with *and*.  A period is not necessary at the end of a title.

Comment: One more question ! This technique does 'cover' the _green lines_ on my PC, will it still work in my friends PC ? I use *docx* format.

Comment: @vvy, I don't know.

Comment: That's Alright ;-) ! I will check it myself. Thanks buddy!

Comment: @vvy, the link mentioned says (or implies) you can turn off grammar check for individual styles.  If you make a separate style for titles I'd expect it and its characteristics to transfer with documents that use it – but again, I don't know.

Comment: In English, *titles, headings*, etc. do not have to be complete sentences - and therefore a grammar check may object to them.